# Tests failed on expected event for simple-map pallet in the substrate-node-template

Tags: substrate-node-template, testing, substrate-recipes

I tried to incorporate the simple-map pallet from the substrate.recipes to the substrate-node-template with the updated mocks.rs and tests.rs.

When I run with `cargo test`, I see the following test results:

```
running 7 tests
test mock::__construct_runtime_integrity_test::runtime_integrity_tests ... ok
test tests::get_throws ... ok
test tests::get_works ... FAILED
test tests::increase_works ... FAILED
test tests::set_works ... FAILED
test tests::take_throws ... ok
test tests::take_works ... FAILED
```

The 4 failed tests have the error message similar to the following:

```
thread 'tests::set_works' panicked at 'events expected',
```

It seems to me that the test failed at the following line of code:

```
System::assert_last_event(expected_event);
```

At https://github.com/limcheekin/substrate-tutorials/blob/recipes/pallets/simple-map/src/tests.rs#L14

Any clue/idea on how to fix the tests and make it pass?
Appreciate your advice and kindly let me know if you need more information.

Feel free to clone the repo and check out the `recipes` branch to re-produce the error locally.

Thank you.

Comment: can you please share your error logs?

Comment: Thanks for response. Found a solution here https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/problem-running-assert-last-event-in-tests-rs